# How to assign int variable to a new string variable ( newVariableText.Text) in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to recreate a flappy bird game from an online tutorial, but I have encountered an issue with my code.

I am trying to set up the program to keep track of my score, but it is not allowing me to convert my int Score variable into a new string(.Text) variable and I have not had luck finding any solutions to this problem.

I also noticed that my using System.Text; is not available as it's grayed out. Could that be the reason and if it is how can I reactivate it or work around it?

Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue would be appreciated.

[image: variables and using]

Comment: Have you tried to convert your integer variable to a string with the .toString() Method?

Comment: In C# method names are Pascal-case, not camel-case.

Comment: @Enigmativity except, irritatingly, in windows forms event handler creation by double click.. Why can't MS just fix that with a simple `Char.ToUpper(proposedName.TrimStart('_')[0])+proposedName.TrimStart('_').Substring(1)` I don't know.. How many years is it now? That said, they're usually `private` so the thinking is probably "who gives a...". Does bug me that the "naming violation" warnings are rife in every WF project I use, or even create; wish the analyzer could resolve all with a single click like it can the "Missing ..Async" one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're keeping the score numerically (good idea, easy to increment etc)

```
int _score = 37;
```

And you want to show it in a label, you need to convert the int to a string:

```
scoreLabel.Text = _score.ToString();
```

Resist the temptation to keep the score as a string and convert it back and forth whenever you need to do math on it:

```
//no
scoreLabel.Text = (int.Parse(scoreLabel.Text) + 1).ToString();
```

While that might helpfully give you some idea of how you can call methods on data and immediately use it to feed into other things (more methods), roundtripping things back and forth from string "just because a string can usefully represent most things" isn't something we strive for in well engineered programs.. Imagine your boss then wants the word "points" in the score string.. that hack becomes:

```
scoreLabel.Text = (int.Parse(scoreLabel.Text.Replace(" points", "")) + 1).ToString() + " points";
```

Now imagine it has to be localized so "points" is in German or English.. It's just going to get worse and worse ;)

---

In your screenshot, `scoreText` is being underlined for a different reason, probably "scoreText does not exist in the current context" - to help with that we'd ideally need to know a bit more about where scoreText is declared (is it even declared?) and as what..

> using System.Text; is not available as it's grayed out.

`using`s gray out for a few reasons, but ultimately it's because they aren't being used. That might be because some necessary reference isn't imported so the code that *would* use the xxx in `using xxx` is in error and not being considered "a use", but all in this might well be tangential to the actual problem you face. System.Text contains some useful things like regular expressions and stringbuilder but assigning a value to the Text property of some class (like a Label) isn't necessarily at all related to anything in the System.Text namespace, so it might not have any bearing on your overall problem. For example, if you put a line `var sb = new StringBuilder();` that `using System.Text;` should just light up, because you're now making use of something in the System.Text namespace, but it doesn't help you with the mission of converting an int to a string or even sounding out why you're trying to use a variable that isn't available to the code, at the point of use

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I tried this approach and attempted it just now but it is still showing an error. "CS0103 The name scoreLabel.Text does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I just guessed at what you might have called the control that you wanted to keep your score in. Assuming that this is indeed windows forms, and you did indeed drop a label onto a form with the intention of using it to display the score, *what did you call the label you dropped on the form?* (What name did you type into the Properties grid (Name) entry, after you created the label?)

Comment: I didn't declare the variable before I tried to assign it. I used the += shortcut to assign it the same time it used it. I am such a noob but i guess we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: If your app doesn't anywhere dcontain anything with a name `scoreText` then that's a root cause of a problem. Draw a new Label on your form, and in the Properties grid, set its (Name) to `scoreText` - exactly that, because C# is case sensitive. In C# everything must be declared before it is used, and for something like a label to appear on a form a bunch of other stuff needs to be set too (its top, left, what other panel/form it's in, its size...).

Comment: You don't see those things being set because when you draw controls onto a form the form designer writes that code and stashes it in a file you don't normally see. You can open it if you want and take a look; it'll be called FormX.Designer.cs, where FormX is what you called your form. The contents of that file, and the contents of the file youre actually writing your code in are merged together when your program is made (because they declare `partial` at the top; compilation merges all partial files with the same name.. just  in case you wonder how *anything* invisible, like your timer, works)

Comment: (Which did just make me realize perhaps one of the steps to the creation of this problem - you've used a bunch of things you maybe can't see being declared, like `floppyBird` and `pipeBottom` and concluded you can just "write something and C# magically knows what it is" - there is, alas, no magic - just that you can't see some of the things you use because theyre declared elsewhere (*.Designer.cs) that's obscured by design. You can, however, right click on `floppyBird` and choose "Go to declaration" if you want to see where it's declared. It got to that place by being drawn on the form)

Comment: I did use microsoft form I checked just now and realized that I didn't name my Label, I only updated the text on the screen (the score font and initial value of 0). Thank you so much. I will correct that now. Last thing after I relabel that what should I do next? do I update my int to reflect that or do I have to create and declare a new variable with that name?

Comment: You'd have a private variable at the top of the class (under the words `public partial class YourFormNameHere` - we refer to these as *fields* or *class level variables* - they're available inside any method throughout the class) e.g. `private int _score = 0;` - c# naming convention tends to be "use a leading underscore for *private* things declared as fields" and "use no leading underscore if the variable is declared inside a method"

Comment: Sorry, I saw you had already answered the last part of my question. Thank You and have a great day.

Comment: No problem; you can mark your question as answered by clicking the gray check mark under the number in the left margin so it turns green. This changes the appearance of the queston on the dashboard so people know it's resolved. If you need further help with another issue, you would raise a new question for it, as SO tries to keep to a "one problem, one question, one answer" flow